# interface ... extends HTMLAttributes<...> {} Does not work correctly in Vite

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vite, react-typescript

An error occurs that the fields (props) "value", "pattern" and so on are not visible to the TextField component.

Error:
Type '{ value: number; pattern: string; onChange: (e: ChangeEvent) => void; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ITextField'.
Property 'value' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ITextField'

```
//TextField.tsx
import { FC, HTMLAttributes } from 'react';

interface ITextField extends HTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement> {}

const TextField: FC<ITextField> = (props) => {
  return ( <input {...props} type='text' /> );
};
export default TextField;
```

```
//App.tsx
import { ChangeEvent, useState } from 'react';
import TextField from './components/TextField';

const App = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState<number>(0);

  const change = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    /* ... */
  };

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <TextField
        value={value}
        pattern='[0-9]*'
        onChange={(e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => change(e)}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
export default App;
```

.................................................